# Having trouble using strpos()

Tags: php, string, foreach, strpos

This function results in 6 matches, although it should result in 2 matches. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
public function displayPrize() {
        $testString = "The cow jumped over the moon";
        $userString = "The cow";

        $magicArray = (explode(" ", $testString));

        foreach ($magicArray as $value) {
            if (strpos(" ", $userString, $value) !== false) {
                $count++;
            }
        }

        echo $count . ' matches';
    }
```

Comment: $value is a string... strpos expects param 3 to be a number...

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Why do you think it should result in 2 matches? What are you expecting that `strpos()` call to do?

Comment: Are you trying to count the words that are in both `$testString` and `$userString`? Explode them both into arrays, then use `array_intersect` to find the elements they have in common.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I mixed up my syntax for explode and strpos. I am getting the desired result now. I need to use strpos() for what I am working on. (Using strpos to test whether words exist in both strings). If I use a foreach loop I won't have to explode the $userString and I can test each $value of $magicArray against the entire $userString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (strpos(" ", $userString, $value) !== false)
```

must become

```
if (strpos($userString, $value) !== false)
```

Comment: Note that if $userString is "Theater coward" you still get 2 matches -- even though Theater coward isn't in the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way using [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$testString = 'The cow jumped over the moon';
$userString = 'The cow';

$testStringArray = explode(' ', $testString);
$userStringArray = explode(' ', $userString);

$result = count( array_intersect($testStringArray, $userStringArray) ); // 2
```